# Change the colour of the links in post notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, hyperlinks

I brought this up before in response to the [notice about the new design](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20107/43351), but it wasn't followed up on. The colour of links barely has any contrast to the surrounding text:

[image]

I have a strong feeling that it is part of the reason why we continually get meta questions about the "missing context" close reason, like [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20829/43351).

This colour scheme does not benefit anyone and it should be changed to make the link stand out, as it was before.

Comment: Hear ear... er... hear!

Comment: We just pushed a fix that should increase the contrast and make the link stand out more.